# Como posicionar texto dentro de uma imagem

Tags: html, css3

Tenho a seguinte imagem e o texto **TESTE**, gostaria de posicionar a palavra **TESTE** onde está o **X** na imagem.

```
<img src="../Content/Images/top.png">
<label>TESTE</label>
```

[image: imagem]

Qual a melhor forma para fazer isso?

Comment: Gostei muito dos dois modelos. Obrigado por postarem me ajudou a esclarecer essa dúvida.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiro você deve colocar ambos so elementos detro de uma `div` ou `figure` com `position: relative` e `display: inline-block;`, então você pode colocar um `position: absolute;` no `label` ou `figcaption` e posicionar ele com as propriedades `top`, `right`, `bottom` e/ou `left`.

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#container figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 145px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
}
```

```html
<figure id="container">
  <img src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/63523.png" />  
  <figcaption>Teste</figcaption>
</figure>
```

No exemplo abaixo, eu possuo a imagem de um cartão de presente e quero possicionar o label dentro da `taja` do mesmo.

Comment: dentro da modal esse seu exemplo fica desconfigurado, o texto aparece fora da imagem

Comment: @Bia você deve ter algum CSS `!important` bagunçando o seu estilo.

Comment: provavelmente é isso.

Answer (score 5):

Utilizando `img` e `label` é possível dessa forma.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

#image {
  position: absolute;
}

#texto {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 32px;
  left: 250px;
  top: 135px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img id="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVoVU.png">
  <label id="texto">TESTE</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar um `figurecaption` para agrupar a imagem e o label, após isso terá de passar para o CSS. Lá você coloca o figurecaption com posição relativa e o label com posição absoluta